# Creating a "VV","VH","VV-VH" composite for each S1 image in loop using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I would like to create a "VV","VH","VV-VH" composite for each feature in my s1 collection. I am not familiar with loops in GEE.

I filtered the data.

```
var myCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2018-12-31')
    .filterBounds(roi);
print(myCollection);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're after a bit more in detail, please?

Comment: I would like to create a time-series stack of S-1 data composed of all the images available in a certain period. And save each image with 3 channels: "VV","VH","VV-VH" composite.

Comment: So like a composite every 16 days?

Comment: Exactly @Daniel !

Answer (score 1):

You can map over the dates you want to create mosaics for, then do a client-side loop over each image and export it. Then you'll manually have to run each individual export task on the right-hand-side "Task" tab.

```
var roi = Map.getBounds(true)
var startDate = ee.Date('2015-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2015-03-01')
var deltaDays = 16

var myCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(roi);

var days = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days')
var composites = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, days.subtract(1), deltaDays)
    .map(function (offsetDays) {
      var start = startDate.advance(offsetDays, 'days')
      var end = start.advance(deltaDays, 'days')
      var masked = ee.Image([ee.Image(), ee.Image()]).rename(['VV', 'VH'])
      var composite = myCollection
        .filterDate(start, end)
        .median()
      var empty = composite.bandNames().size().eq(0)
      composite = masked.addBands(composite, null, true)
      return composite
        .addBands(
          composite.expression('c.VV - c.VH', {c: composite})
            .rename('VV-VH')
        )
        .select(['VV', 'VH', 'VV-VH'])
        .set('start', start.format('yyyy-MM-dd')) // Include dates of composite
        .set('end', end.format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
        .set('empty', empty)
        .clip(roi)
    })
  )
  .filterMetadata('empty', 'equals', 0) // Drop empty images
  .toList(1000)

composites.size().evaluate(function (count) {
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var image = ee.Image(composites.get(i))
    print(image.get('start'))
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: image,
      description: 'S1_' + i,
      scale: 20,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
  }
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0af7a65f8efff9edf8ec2a64b4198f1d

Comment: Thank you so much @Daniel. Is there a way to see of which exact date the composite is made of? And how can I get the other composites? In order to save them.

Comment: You've got 'start' and 'end' properties on each composite indicating the date range.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel for the valuable help! But I am still struggling for exporting to drive the single composite of the image collection. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I've updated the answer with export code.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. Last thing, if you can help me. I would like to have linear values of the products. So I should: .log10().multiply(10.0)   where I can add this for all the 3 bands? Best

Comment: Try this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/47334c52941eff9b25f85f6cf64c46fc